# Function to plot model with one variable varying and others constant

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization

It's simple, I can't for the life of me remember how this procedure is called, hence I was not able to find the function to do so. I want to explore the effects and gradients of a simple lm() model by plotting the response of one variable at a time, the others being kept constant.

Can anybody tell me which function to use to do so? I seem to remember it's a function generating several plots, or something like this.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: looks like it could something akin to sensitivity analysis... Still not sure what to use though.

Answer (score 1):

In JMP, these are called Profilers or [Profile Plots](http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Interpreting_the_Profiles.shtml):

[image]

Not sure about R, but I found a [CV question involving a similar R plot using a function called "profile"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100072/how-can-be-profile-plots-in-evt-interpreted-and-what-is-the-theoretical-nature-o). Maybe it will lead to something you're looking for.